# Blazor (server) strange DateTime.Now behaviour

Tags: azure, blazor-server-side

I am experiencing a strange behaviour with my blazor (server side) app hosted on azure.

What is happening is that the DateTime.UTCNow shows me the wrong date.
This happens in a very specific situation.
I publish the site, then run it, all working fine. If I then keep the app running all day, next day when requesting the DateTime it gives me yesterdays date. This is super weird.
It appears to me as if the app keeps the DateTime from the original Time of publishing the app. If i close the browser and then go to azure and restart my app, then open my browser again and check for the time. It is all fine.

I am not sure if it is an issue with Blazor or with Azure. Or if this is even expected behaviour. Kind of strange if it was to be honest.

Any hint on how to solve this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Post your code. Where do you see that date and how is it generated? Almost certainly, your code is caching an old date somewhere. `DateTime.Now` will always return the current local time. In Blazor Server that would be the local time on the server

Comment: Check the date settings in your server.